# Sending large amount of data between Qt threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a `QThread` which generates a fairly large amount of data regularly (couple of megabytes per second), and it needs to transmit it to the parent (GUI) thread.

I'm afraid I'm not that certain in the inner workings of `QThread` so I would like to ask for a best practice.

Obviously, the most direct way to transmit data is to just `emit` an array. However, how efficient is this? Does Qt know about where it is used and avoids deep copying it when sending and receiving it?

If not, I can gladly just allocate the memory in the main thread and give a pointer to the child thread where it will write the data (and only `emit` short messages about the progress). This does not seem to be the most elegant solution to me, this is why I'm asking.

If Qt avoids copying the data in multiple buffers when emitting and receiving, is it guaranteed in all systems? I don't have the resources to try benchmarking it under various OSs.

Comment: We need to know more. Is it acceptable for the main thread to lose data? What does the main thread do with the data, anyway? But whatever your needs, I can't believe that emitting an array is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`QThread`'s inner workings are irrelevant: they play no role in how the event loops work. When you `emit` a signal in a `QObject` that lives in a thread different from the slot's object, the signal will be posted as a `QMetaCallEvent` to the event queue of the receiving thread.  The event loop running in the receiving thread will then act on this event and execute the call into the slot that was connected to the emitted signal.

So, no matter what happens, whatever data you send through the signal will eventually end up as a payload in an instance of QEvent-derived class.

The meat of the issue is when the `QMetaCallEvent` reaches the event loop and the container gets passed into the slot as an argument. Of course the copy constructors could be called plenty of times along the way. Below is some simple code that demonstrates how many times the copy constructor and default constructor are in fact called

- on the elements of the data members of an implicitly shared copy-on-write container (QVector),
- on a custom class that stands in for a container.

You'll be pleasantly surprised :)

Since Qt containers are implicitly shared copy-on-write, their copy construction has negligible cost: all that's done is a reference counter is incremented atomically on construction. None of the data members are copied, for example.

Alas, pre-11 C++ shows its ugly side: if the slot code modifies the container in any way, there's no way to pass references to the slot in such a way that would let the compiler know that the original container is not needed anymore. Thus: if the slot receives a const reference to the container, you're guaranteed that no copies will be made. If the slot receives a writeable copy of the container *and* you modify it, there will be a completely unnecessary copy made since the instance alive at the call site is no longer needed. In C++-11 you'd pass an rvalue reference as a parameter. Passing an rvalue reference in a function call ends the lifetime of the passed object in the caller.

Sample code output:

```
"Started" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 0 
"Created Foo" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 100 
"Created Bar" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 100 
"Received signal w/const container" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 100 
"Received signal w/copy of the container" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 100 
"Made a copy" copies: 100 assignments: 1 default instances: 101 
"Reset" copies: 0 assignments: 0 default instances: 0 
"Received signal w/const class" copies: 2 assignments: 0 default instances: 1 
"Received signal w/copy of the class" copies: 3 assignments: 0 default instances: 1
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <QtCore>

class Class {
    static QAtomicInt m_copies;
    static QAtomicInt m_assignments;
    static QAtomicInt m_instances;
public:
    Class() { m_instances.fetchAndAddOrdered(1); }
    Class(const Class &) { m_copies.fetchAndAddOrdered(1); }
    Class & operator=(const Class &) { m_assignments.fetchAndAddOrdered(1); return *this; }
    static void dump(const QString & s = QString()) {
        qDebug() << s << "copies:" << m_copies << "assignments:" << m_assignments << "default instances:" << m_instances;
    }
    static void reset() {
        m_copies = 0;
        m_assignments = 0;
        m_instances = 0;
    }
};

QAtomicInt Class::m_instances;
QAtomicInt Class::m_copies;
QAtomicInt Class::m_assignments;

typedef QVector<Class> Vector;

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Vector)

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Vector v;
public:
    Foo() : v(100) {}
signals:
    void containerSignal(const Vector &);
    void classSignal(const Class &);
public slots:
    void sendContainer() { emit containerSignal(v); }
    void sendClass() { emit classSignal(Class()); }
};

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Bar() {}
signals:
    void containerDone();
    void classDone();
public slots:
    void containerSlotConst(const Vector &) {
        Class::dump("Received signal w/const container");
    }
    void containerSlot(Vector v) {
        Class::dump("Received signal w/copy of the container");
        v[99] = Class();
        Class::dump("Made a copy");
        Class::reset();
        Class::dump("Reset");
        emit containerDone();
    }
    void classSlotConst(const Class &) {
        Class::dump("Received signal w/const class");
    }
    void classSlot(Class) {
        Class::dump("Received signal w/copy of the class");
        emit classDone();
        //QThread::currentThread()->quit();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<Vector>("Vector");
    qRegisterMetaType<Class>("Class");

    Class::dump("Started");
    QThread thread;
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    Class::dump("Created Foo");
    bar.moveToThread(&thread);
    Class::dump("Created Bar");
    QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), &foo, SLOT(sendContainer()));
    QObject::connect(&foo, SIGNAL(containerSignal(Vector)), &bar, SLOT(containerSlotConst(Vector)));
    QObject::connect(&foo, SIGNAL(containerSignal(Vector)), &bar, SLOT(containerSlot(Vector)));
    QObject::connect(&bar, SIGNAL(containerDone()), &foo, SLOT(sendClass()));
    QObject::connect(&foo, SIGNAL(classSignal(Class)), &bar, SLOT(classSlotConst(Class)));
    QObject::connect(&foo, SIGNAL(classSignal(Class)), &bar, SLOT(classSlot(Class)));
    QObject::connect(&bar, SIGNAL(classDone()), &thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    thread.start();
    a.exec();
    thread.wait();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Wow - that's a pretty comprehensive answer!

Comment: Great example sorting out Qt's shared containers when coupled with `QThread`. Even got some C++-11 love as a bonus. Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

When communicating large buffers, it's 'traditional' to new() buffer objects in the producer thread and, when loaded up, queue/emit/whatever the *buffer to the consumer thread and immediately new() another one, (into the same *buffer var), for the next load of data.

Issue: if your GUI thread cannot keep up, you will get memory runaway unless you take some flow-control measure(eg. pre-allocating a pool of *buffers and 'circulating' them).

What I usually do is pre-allocate some buffer instances in a loop, (up to thousands in a big server), and push their instances onto a producer-consumer 'pool queue'.  If a child thread wants to load data from some network connection into a buffer, it must pop one from the pool and load it up.  It can then queue/emit/whatever the buffer to a consumer thread and pop another buffer for any more data that may come in.  The consumer thread gets the bufer, processes the data and pushes the 'used' buffer back onto the pool queue for re-use. This provides flow-control: if the child thread loads buffers faster than the consumer thread can process them, it will find the pool empty and block on it until the consumer thread returns some used buffers, so capping buffer/memory use, (and also avoiding continual new/dispose, or GC in those languages that support it).

I like to dump the pool queue count to a GUI status bar on a 1-sec timer - this allows me to watch buffer use, (and quickly spot if any leak:).

Comment: What is the decisive advantage in allocating memory inside the child thread and passing a pointer to the main, versus allocating in the main and passing the pointer to the child at creation?

Comment: The child thread is the data producer - it knows when a buffer is full and so when to queue off its pointer and create/depool another buffer*.  The GUI thread, the consumer, does not need to know or manage the child thread buffer allocation - it can freely process buffers as they come in, knowing that the child thread has completely abandoned the use of it and is either idle or filling up a different buffer instance.  As long as the child immediately creates/depools a new buffer instance after queueing one off, there is no chance that the two threads can ever access the same buffer instance.

Comment: Btw an easy way to avoid any chance of a memory leak is to emit a shared_ptr (or if you prefer Qt APIs, a QSharedDataPointer) rather than a raw C++ pointer.  That way no matter what happens you know the array will be freed when both threads are no longer using it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - yesh, sort of.. I like to use a pools - I notice very quickly if objects leak.  If I'm not at my box monitoring the count 'manually' I get 'notification' when I return, (the pool count is 0 and the child blocked, but the GUI is still up:).  a shared_ptr should be OK for non-pooled approaches, (anything but non-reseatable, nearly-useless C++ references).